# jQuery - How to get a single value[]

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<div class="trackon" id="<?="trackline1">
    <input type="hidden" name="atloriginal[]" value="1" /></span>
</div>

<div class="trackon" id="<?="trackline2">
    <input type="hidden" name="atloriginal[]" value="2" /></span>
</div>

<div class="trackon" id="<?="trackline3">
    <input type="hidden" name="atloriginal[]" value="3" /></span>
</div>
```

How can I change the hidden value of trackline2 on "hello"? I'm here :

```
$('#trackline2').find("DON'T KNOW HOW TO WRITE THIS").val("hello");
```

is is possible to set that value to an input array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just one input

```
$('#trackline2 input').val("hello");
```

If you have more than one, you need to have some way of identifying them. May be using name...

```
$('#trackline2 input[name="atloriginal[]"]').val("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `trackon` class objects are the only ones on the page, and they are always in order, you could use:

```
$('.trackon').eq(2).val('hello')
```

Comment: I meant that there are no other `trackon` class objects, not that you didn't use other classes